# Can browser / Anti-virus software block requests made to direct IP addresses instead of domain name?

Tags: node.js, security, browser, ip, antivirus

I have few APIs implemented on one remote node server and I want to make requests to that server through my web page, but is it the case that browser / anti-virus s/w will consider requests made to direct IP address as dangerous and might block them entirely ?

Is it necessary to assign a domain name to that remote node server ?.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I don't think an antivirus would stop a program making requests to a server simply because the request was made out to an IP address, this is generally not the best practise. You should use a domain name, or subdomain for your server. This helps identify the server and in the case that the IP address of the server should change, the application does not need to be updated because DNS will do the bulk of the work next time the application attempts a connection.

TLDR: It will work, but it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

They can and they do. In the end of 2017 when several webminers such as coinhive become popular some anti-viruses started to block the websockets connections directly, even if the miner tries to connect using only the ip address.

It's not necessary to assign a domain name to your server, but you won't bypass anti-viruses that way.